# Disabling and enabling UI components in Unity3D doesn't render them

Tags: user-interface, canvas, unity-game-engine

My UI setup in Unity has an error label that is activated by code whenever a certain event happens in my UI (button press). The first time said event happens, it renders okay. When I hit back on that menu, the label gets deactivated using SetActive(false). When I press the initial button again, the Error Label GameObject appears as active in the scene hierarchy, however it doesn't render on screen (if i manually deactivate it and activate again via the editor interface, it does render okay). This happens both in the editor and when it is built and run on a target device (iPhone and Android).

I've noticed this is a known issue in Unity 5.6, however I haven't been able to find any workaround until it is solved. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT: Button code, as requested.

The variable component denotes the GameObject which gets activated by the button. This group holds the current UI screen which gets deactivated.

```
public void ActionOnClick () {
                if (component) {
                    component.SetActive(true);
                }
                thisGroup.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please share your code to answer

Comment: It's just a UI GameObject being activated via SetActive(). As mentioned already, the GameObject does become active, however the content(e.g. text and image) doesn't get rendered.

Comment: We would like to see the code involved in the "back" button on the error menu to insure that you *aren't* doing something else that is having the unexpected side effect you are seeing, as if I were to use your description to try and replicate your issue, I would get "works for me." That is: I would be unable to duplicate your problem.  Also use an @-mention to reply or we won't get a notification.

Comment: @Draco18s there you go.

Answer (score 0):

you can try rebuild the UI Element like this :

```
myGameObject.GetComponent<Graphic>().Rebuild();
```

Or just Rebuild() if you're already on a component that inherit Graphic,
You can also try to move the object so that the internal state of the object get dirty and unity rebuild it, like this :

```
myGameObject.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Just tried both, neither worked. Same behaviour as before.

Comment: is component in some sort of parent ? because it may be that the gameObject is activeSelf but the parent is unactive.

Comment: It's not that. The gameObject and all it's parents are active.

Comment: Upload the part of your project that is in fault, like this, no one will be able to help you out i believe